# Extension of a prime ideal in a Dedekind domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose that $A$ is a Dedekind domain and that $P$ is a prime ideal of $A$. Suppose that $K$ is the fraction field of $A$ and that $L$ is some finite separable extension of $K$. If $B$ is the integral closure of $A$ in $L$, is it necessarily the case that $PB\neq B$? If so, why?

I am not sure why this question has been closed. Apparently it has offended the hall monitors of MSE by contradicting some nebulous rule. However, I believe it is a straightforward question (and the comments indicate an answer exists in some book which I do not own and do not have access to!) and I hope the question will be reopened. Perhaps, after all, someone else has the same question!

Comment: @Mathmo123 Are you implicitly using that $A$ is integrally closed here? Since $y=1/x$ implies that $y\in K\cap B$?

Comment: @Mathmo123 your argument is incorrect: $PB$ is *not* the set of products, but the set of sums of products.  When $P$ is a principal ideal, $PB$ is a set of products, but not for a general ideal. The product is always defined as a sum of products to guarantee it is an additive group.

Comment: This result is proved very early in Lang's "Algebraic Number Theory" for the case of a prime ideal and an integral ring extension: if $A \subset B$ are (nonzero) rings and $B$ is integral over $A$, then for each prime ideal $P$ of $A$, $PB \not= B$ and there is a prime $Q$ of $B$ such that $Q \cap A = P$.  See Section 3 of Chapter I. The proof uses localization.  It has nothing to do with Dedekind domains or separable extensions of fraction fields. There could be a different proof specific to the setting of Dedekind domains, but the general result for all integral ring extensions is important.

Comment: @KCd Thanks, I understand the mistake. However, I'm still confused by why it suffices to prove the result for the localization $B_P$.

Comment: It doesn't suffice to prove the case of the localization: you have to then argue why the general case is implied by the local case.  Every result that involves reduction to the case of local rings needs a reason why that case implies the general case.

Comment: This is called the Lying Over Theorem. It's proved in basically every commutative algebra book: there are many references listed on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Going_up_and_going_down), such as Atiyah-MacDonald, and it's Theorem 2.2.2 in [these notes](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~r-ash/ComAlg/ComAlg2.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, because of the *Lying over* property: as $B$ is integral over $A$ and the morphism  $A\longrightarrow B$ is injective, there exists a prime ideal $\mathfrak q\in\operatorname{Spec}B$ such that $\mathfrak q\cap A=\mathfrak p$, so $\mathfrak p B\subset \mathfrak q\varsubsetneq B$.

Comment: I feel like this might be circular. Surely, to prove the lying over theorem, you already need to know that $\mathfrak p B$ is a proper ideal...

Comment: @Mathmo123: Not at all. In Bourbaki (*Commutative Algebra*, ch. 5), they first consider the case $A$ local, then proceed by localisation in the non-local case.

Comment: They show that if $\mathfrak  m$ is a maximal ideal of $B$, $\mathfrak m\cap A$ is a maximal ideal of $A$ with a classic lemma ( if $A,A'$ are integral domains and $A\to A'$ is injective and integral, then $A$ is a field iff $A'$ is). As $A$ is local, this means $\mathfrak m\cap A=\mathfrak p$.

Comment: They're basic tools in commutative algebra…